# Find word with certain character in javascript and replace whole word

Tags: javascript

I want to search for the char `$` in a string. However, this char can be joined to multiple things, even whitespaces. Few examples:

```
" $ "
"$another"
" $an other"
" on$more "
```

What I want to do is **remove the WHOLE word after finding $** so the outcome for the examples would be:

```
" "
""
"  other"
" "
```

I hope I made my point... is this possible to do without loops **in pure JavaScript?**

Comment: Are you keeping the spaces before or after the removed word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `regex`

```
/([^ "]*\$[^ "]*)/g
```

See working `regex` **[here](https://regex101.com/r/mP5xU5/1)**.

Check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/bz5xzwb8/)**.

```js
var re = /([^ "]*\$[^ "]*)/g; 
var str = '" $ " ; "$another" ; " $an other" ; " on$more ";';
var subst = ''; 
 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);

alert(result);
```

Comment: this does not account for special  characters in the word does it?

Comment: It will work for all special characters except `"`. See [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/mP5xU5/2) for clarification

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `[\S]*\$[\S]*` regular expression and the `replace()` method.

```js
var strings = [" $ ", "$another", " $an other", " on$more "];

var re = /[\S]*\$[\S]*/;

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    strings[i] = strings[i].replace(re, '');
}


console.log(strings);
```

and you will get `[ '  ', '', '  other', '  ' ]`